# rtsp link has delay and can not get http link

Tags: video-streaming, vlc, rtsp, ip-camera, onvif

I have a **[Foscam X2  1080p](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07Z56ZNPD)** ip camera, the rtsp link has 2 seconds delay so I decided to use http link for streaming BUT I can not get http link I try all below links but no answer.

http://cameraip:port/videostream.cgi?user=[USERNAME]&pwd=[PASSWORD]

http://cameraip:port/videostream.asf?user=[USERNAME]&pwd=[PASSWORD]

this is my rtsp link:
rtsp://test:Test_1020@192.168.0.151:88/videoMain
'test' is user and 'Test_1020' is pass.

any help? to fix rtsp delay or get http link??
thank you

Comment: oh, that's an amazing question!

Answer (score 0):

It's completely normal to have a 2 seconds delay in RTSP and commercial conventional IP cameras.
If you would have a better performance with minimum delay I recommend you to use industrial cameras with global shutter.